# Contractions in a proof of the Yosida approximation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In Kallenberg, Foundations of Modern Probability they mention in the proof of Lemma 19.7 (Yosida approximation) that certain operators are contractions. I don't know how to show this and need your help.

> **Lemma 19.7** (Yosida approximation). If $(T_t)_t$ is a $C_0$ Feller semigroup on a compact, separable metric space and $A: D_A\rightarrow X$ its generator, then for any $u\in D_A$ we have that
> $$
> T_t^\lambda u=e^{tA^\lambda u}=e^{t\lambda R_\lambda Au}\rightarrow T_tu,
> $$
> where $R_\lambda=(\lambda-A)^{-1}=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}T_tu \mathrm{dt}$ denotes the resolvents.

In the proof they mention that $(T_t^\lambda)_t$ is a contraction semigroup. The semigroup property is easy to show, and also continuity makes sense.

**Questions**

1. How do I show that $||T_t^\lambda u||\leq||u||$ holds?
2. Can we weaken the requirement that $(T_t)_t$ is a $C_0$ Feller semigroup to something more general? Can you provide me a more general result on this (references)?

**Ansatz**

1. We could use that the resolvents are contractions, but this seems too rough of an estimate to work. I guess we need to include the $\lambda$ and $t$ in some way ($||T_t^\lambda u||=e^{t\lambda||R_\lambda Au||}\leq e^{t\lambda||Au||}$). One could also try to write down the integral definition of the resolvent to yield some expression, but it seems not helpful as one is only able to do a similar estimate as before:
   $$
   ||T_t^\lambda u||=e^{t\lambda||\int_0^\infty e^{-s\lambda}AT_su\mathrm{ds}||}
   $$

Comment: I didn't understand the definition of the operators $T_t^\lambda$. Of course we want them to be linear and thus the definition written in the citation above is already wrong. It should be $T_t^\lambda u=e^{tA^\lambda}u$ instead of $T_t^\lambda u=e^{tA^\lambda u}$.